# Unity - scale UI element based on closeness to a target?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Ok Im using the https://bitbucket.org/beksomega/unityuiscrollsnaps/src omnidirectional scroll and I have this set up where the boxes snap to the center purple box with a drag:

[image]

I want the element that is "selected" or whichever element is closest to the target to scale up, like Apple's watch apps:

[image]

In the scripts I have a lot of functions, like this one:

```
private Vector2 FindClosestSnapPositionToPosition(Vector2 position)
        {
            EnsureLayoutHasRebuilt();

            Vector2 selected = Vector2.zero;
            float shortestDistance = Mathf.Infinity;

            foreach (Vector2 snapPosition in m_SnapPositions)
            {
                float distance = Vector2.Distance(snapPosition, position);

                if (distance < shortestDistance)
                {
                    shortestDistance = distance;
                    selected = snapPosition;
                }
            }

            return selected;
        }
```

And can print the selected or closest item. How could I scale according to closeness to the target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to scale between some bounds. Lets say it begins at scale 1 and you want to reach a size S. We can define a distance D, relative between the pointer and the object, where the object starts to scale.
You could do something like this.

```
/* Constants */
const float S = 2.0f; // The maximum size you want to get when closest
const float D = 5.0f; // The distance where you start to scale
const float E = 1.0f; // The distance where the object will not scale more (i.e. reached the maximum)

float GetIconSize(Vector2 pointer, Vector2 icon)
{
    // Get the value between 0 and 1 from the distance between
    float factor = Mathf.InverseLerp(D, E, Vector2.Distance(pointer, icon));

    // Return the interpolated value size depending on the distance
    return Mathf.Lerp(1.0f, S, factor);
}
```

And then apply to the object (I'm assuming it is called "icon")

```
float size = GetIconSize(Vector2 pointer, Vector2 icon);
icon.transform.localScale = new Vector2(size, size);
```

To the function you have to pass the position of your pointer, mouse, finger, etc and the second parameter is the icon or target that you want to scale.
Basically you need to know the factor of distance between both, and with that factor interpolate between the minimum scale and maximum scale.
I hope this is what you wanted, and if not, tell me.